# How to re-arrange an expression based on an integration

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have an expression that includes some integrations. I find the derivative of the expression which results in a long-expression. I wanna rewrite the result based on one of the integrations. I would be thankful to know how I can re-write the following expression:

```
D[t1* Integrate[(u - z)*f[u], {u, z, Infinity}] * Integrate[(u - z)*f[u], {u, z, Infinity}] + 
  t2* Integrate[f[u], {u, 0, z}] * Integrate[(u - z)*f[u], {u, z, Infinity}], z]
```

I want to re-arrange the result based on `Integrate[(u - z)*f[u], {u, z, Infinity}]` , then, based on `Integrate[f[u], {u, 0, z}]`.

I have tried "Reduce" by I faced an error. Also, how it is possible to replace each integration with a symbol like `s1 =Integrate[(u - z)*f[u], {u, z, Infinity}]`  and `s2 =Integrate[f[u], {u, 0, z}]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replacement rules to rewrite the results in terms of `s1[z]` and `s2[z]`:

```
expr = D[t1*Integrate[(u - z)*f[u], {u, z, Infinity}]*
         Integrate[(u - z)*f[u], {u, z, Infinity}] + 
         t2*Integrate[f[u], {u, 0, z}]*
         Integrate[(u - z)*f[u], {u, z, Infinity}], z]

reprules = {Integrate[(u_ - z)*f[u_], {u_, z, Infinity}] -> s1[z], 
            Integrate[f[u_], {u_, 0, z}] -> s2[z]}

Simplify[expr /. reprules] // InputForm

(* t2*f[z]*s1[z] + Integrate[-f[u], {u, z, Infinity}]*(2*t1*s1[z] + t2*s2[z]) *)
```

I have used the pattern `u_` so that these same replacement rules can be applied if you use a different dummy variable in your integrations, though this case doesn't arise in the code you've provided.

```
Integrate[(w - z)*f[w], {w, z, Infinity}] /. reprules

(* s1[z] *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.